# What does "make a sissy of somebody" mean?

Tags: phrase-meaning, word-meaning

In the movie "The power of the dog", a man  talks to a boy that behaves like a sissy “**Don’t let your mom make a sissy of you**” ([see the link about the movie here](https://cinemasight.wordpress.com/tag/benedict-cumberbatch/)).

What does "**make a sissy of somebody**" mean?

Is it common in everyday English?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A sissy is a person (usually male)  who acts in a way that the speaker considers effeminate, insufficiently "manly", or simply weak or cowardly. The term is in common use in US English. It can be used as anything from a  mild tease to an intended serious insult. It is almost never intended as positive.

The idea that someone's influence can "make" a person, particularly a boy, into a sissy is not uncommon, although less common than  it used to be.